# wide spread sub menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

Actually I want my menu to be something like sub-menu in this website http://www.maxhealthcare.org.

Here is my HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Patient and Visitor Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hospital Network</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Specialities</a>

        <ul>
            <p><span>Eye Care</span></p>
            <li><a href="<?=site_url('ourspeciality/ourspeciality_list_services')?>">List of Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team that cares</a></li>

            <p><span>Gasterology</span></p>
            <li><a href="#">List of Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team that cares</a></li>

            <p><span>General Surgery</span></p>
            <li><a href="#">List of Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team that cares</a></li>

            <p><span>Internal Medicine</span></p>
            <li><a href="#">List of Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team that cares</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Preventive Health Plans</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">For Medical Professionals</a></li>
</ul>
```

and CSS is;

```
#menu ul
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:11px 150px;
    background-color:#013773;
    float:left;
    width:77.7%;
    list-style:none;
}
#menu ul li
{
height:100%;
width:auto;
margin:0px 5px;
padding:12px;   
cursor:pointer;
position:relative;
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFF;
font-size:15px;
}
#menu ul li:hover
{
background-color:#FFF;
color:#013773;
}
#menu ul li ul
{
display:none;
background-color:#FFF;
}
#menu ul li ul li
{
display:block;
width:90%;
position:relative;
color:inherit;
margin:0px;
font-weight:normal;
font-size:12px;
padding:0px;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul
{
display:block;
position:absolute;
margin:10px 0px;
padding:20px;
height:auto;
width:300px;
border-bottom:1px #CCC solid;
border-right:1px #CCC solid;
border-left:1px #CCC solid;
float:left;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul li
{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
padding:10px;
font-weight:normal;
}
#menu ul li ul li:hover
{
font-weight:normal;
}
```

In the sub-menu i will expand my menu items as it is in the example website. Can some one tell me how to do this?

Comment: The link you attached doesn't lead to a real website, it leads to a placeholder page.  You'd be better off writing a brief description of the desired behavior, perhaps with a screenshot or two to illustrate it.  Also, if you can narrow down the HTML and CSS to just that which is necessary to demonstrate your problem and needs, it'll be easier for people to answer.

Comment: I am really sorry @ASGM. The link is http://www.maxhealthcare.in